# shift array without indexOfOutBounds

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 array's with the same length. array `$gPositionStudents` and array `$gPositionInternships`. Each student is assigned to a different internship, That part works.

Now I want the first element (index 0) of `$gPositionStudent` refer to the second (index 1) element of array `$gPositionInternship`. That implicitly means that the last element of `$gPositionStudents` refer to the first element of `$gPositionInternship`. (I included a picture of my explanation).

[image]

My Code is:

```
// Make table
$header = array();
$header[] = array('data' => 'UGentID');
$header[] = array('data' => 'Internships');
// this big array will contains all rows
// global variables.
global $gStartPositionStudents;
global $gStartPositionInternships;
//var_dump($gStartPositionInternships);
$rows = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($gStartPositionStudents as $value) {
    foreach($gStartPositionInternships as $value2) {
        // each loop will add a row here.
        $row = array();
        // build the row
        $row[] = array('data' => $value[0]['value']);            
        //if($value[0] != 0 || $value[0] == 0) {
        $row[] = array('data' => $gStartPositionInternships[$i]);           
    }
    $i++;
    // add the row to the "big row data (contains all rows)
    $rows[] = array('data' => $row);
}
$output = theme('table', $header, $rows);
return $output;
```

Now I want that I can choose how many times, we can shift. 1 shift or 2 or more shifts. What I want exists in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
//get the array keys for the interns and students...
$intern_keys = array_keys($gStartPositionInternships);
$student_keys = array_keys($gStartPositionStudents);

//drop the last intern key off the end and pin it to the front.
array_unshift($intern_keys, array_pop($intern_keys));

//create a mapping array to join the two arrays together.
$student_to_intern_mapping = array();
foreach($student_keys as $key=>$value) {
    $student_to_intern_mapping[$value] = $intern_keys[$key];
}
```

You'll need to modify it to suit the rest of your code, but hopefully this will demonstrate a technique you could use. Note the key line here is the one which does `array_unshift()` with `array_pop()`. The comment in the code should explain what it's doing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do `array_slice($gPositionsStudents, 0, X)` where X is the number of moves to shift. This slices of a number of array elements. Then do `array_merge($gPositionsStudents, $arrayOfSlicedOfPositions);` to append these to the end of the original array.

Then you can do an array_combine to create one array with key=>value pairs from both arrays.